# Inclusion of Total Users metric filtering table in Looker Studio report using GA4 connector

Tags: looker-studio, google-analytics-4

I've created a table of data in Looker Studio that connects directly to a GA4 property using the GA4 connector. I simply want to report on engagement by hostname and as such the table has a dimension of Hostname and then multiple engagement related metrics to report on. As you can see, when Total Users isn't included in the report, over 34 hostnames are reported on, but when Total Users is included in the report, this drops down to just 20.

**Before total users added:**

[image: before Total users]

**After Total Users added:**
[image: after Total Users]

I've experienced the same thing in another report where getting Total Users by Country does exactly the same thing, showing over 100 Countries if Total Users isn't included but only 1 if it is.

It looks from [this](https://support.google.com/looker-studio/thread/237878934/ga4-total-user-metric-no-longer-working-correctly-on-gls-table?hl=en) as though someone else has had the same issue as me but didn't get a response.

Any ideas? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you try another user-scope metric like new user or active user? If your issue still remains, maybe it's due to cardinality issues or limit quotas.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @aliizadi. Unfortunately same issue with active users. Direct from the API is serving restricted results too despite definitely not hitting quota limits. Because it's also happening when dimension is for example, country, I don't think cardinality is the issue.